# When using cudaMalloc, how to specify an address of a variable?

Tags: cuda, gpu, checkpoint, heterogeneous

I'm trying to do the checkpoint/restart(CR) of CUDA applications using DMTCP.

When restoring, the memory address of a device memory region reallocated after checkpointing must be the same as that before checkpointing.

```
int Nbytes = 40;
void **A_d;

int address = 0;

*A_d = (void*)0x7ffe69da6f80;

CHECK(cudaMalloc(A_d, Nbytes));
printf("address is: %p\n", *A_d);
CHECK(cudaFree(*A_d));


return 0;
```

I have tried for several times, the pointer address are totally different.

Does anyone have any idea for this?

Comment: Are you sure DMTCP supports CUDA? Since It does not use kernel module nor any kernel modification and cudaMalloc makes allocations on the device that DMTCP cannot control, It make sense the checkpointing strategy will not work on device related data including device allocations.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'm not sure, but I am trying to make it

Answer (score 4):

You cannot specify the address, nor do you have any control over the address returned by  any CUDA allocator:

`cudaMalloc`, `cudaMallocHost`, `cudaHostAlloc`, `cudaMallocManaged`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I want to specify the address of the variables so THAT I can try to restart the kernel function. But now, I don't know how to specify the address, and I don't know how to restart the kernel function

Comment: There is research for restarting CUDA with DMTCP: https://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/gene/papers/sc20.pdf called CRUM, CRAC, CRCUDA But is is probably easier to implement a simple solution yourself. E.g. if blocks do not interact and do not modify the same memory they read, just restart complete blocks within a CUDA grid. Or divide your kernel into several smaller kernels.

Comment: For real CR Cuda also has a debug API, but I think that would be a complicated project to implement and very dependent on special support by Nvidia (for added documentation of interna, for added driver functions, for continuous support with new architectures, for consulting by Nvidia specialists) and probably involve modifying SASS code for restarting kernels. So it probably would be more complicated than implementing a Cuda simulator on SASS level. I think the broader public has not even the SASS opcodes for complete disassembly available yet.

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, you are right. Implementing the restart of a cuda program is very complicated. To fully support CUDA, one have to know the CUDA internal implementation. But this is unlikely for us.